# Qemu: Please remove the installation medium then press enter

Tags: ubuntu, virtual-machine, qemu

### Context

After installing Ubuntu 22.10 on  Qemu with:

```
cd ~/Downloads
qemu-img create ~/Downloads/ubuntu22.img 20G
qemu-system-x86_64 --enable-kvm -m 1024 -machine smm=off -cdrom ~/Downloads/ubuntu-22.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso -boot order=d ~/Downloads/ubuntu22.img
```

QEMU asks: `<Please remove installation medium and press enter>.`

However, I did not find a button to remove the installation medium.

### Question

How can one ensure Ubuntu boots on a fresh installation in QEMU when one is asked: `<Please remove installation medium and press enter>`?

### Attempts

If I power off the device and start it again, it will ask whether one wants to try/install Ubuntu, and it does not boot into the already installed Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One can click `power off` to turn off the QEMU emulator. Next one can launch the QEMU emulator without the "boot" cdrom option, and directly launch the installed Ubuntu os with:

```
qemu-system-x86_64 --enable-kvm -m 1024 -machine smm=off -boot order=d ~/Downloads/ubuntu22.img
```

The difference is that the original `iso` file is ommitted: `-cdrom ~/Downloads/ubuntu-22.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso`